# Method doesn't set value of an object

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and have no idea why doesn't it work. I'm trying to create 3 methods that create a new Vehicle object with different properties. I've tried to do it with polymorphism but it's been even worse. I bet the answer to that is so easy..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;

namespace PetrolStation
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {               

        Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(DisplayTimeEvent);
        aTimer.Interval = 1000; // 1000=1s
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
        Console.ReadLine();

        void DisplayTimeEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int temp = rand.Next(1, 3);

            if (temp == 2)
            {
                Vehicles vehicle = new Vehicles();
                vehicle.newCar();
                Console.Out.WriteLine("test", vehicle.carType); // it should print "car" after test but it doesn't

            }
            if (temp == 3)
            {
                Vehicles vehicle = new Vehicles();
                vehicle.newVan();
                Console.Out.WriteLine("test", vehicle.carType);// it should print "van" after test but it doesn't


            }
        }

    }

}
```

Second class:

```
public class Vehicles
    {

    public string carType;
    public string fuelType;
    public int tankCap;
    public  double fuelInTank;
    public Random rand = new Random();



    public  void newCar()
    {
        carType = "Car";
        tankCap = 40;
        fuelInTank = rand.NextDouble() * 10;
        int tempFuelType = rand.Next(1, 3);
        switch (tempFuelType)
        {
            case 1:
                fuelType = "petrol";
                break;
            case 2:
                fuelType = "Diesel";
                break;
            case 3:
                fuelType = "LPG";
                break;
        }

    }
    public  void newVan()
    {
        carType = "van";
        tankCap = 80;
        fuelInTank = rand.NextDouble() * 20;
        int tempFuelType = rand.Next(1, 2);
        if (tempFuelType == 1)
        {
            fuelType = "Diesel";
        }
        else
        {
            fuelType = "LPG";
        }


    }
```

Comment: I'm not talking about your realization of class, your example meets almost in all OOP languages books, somewhere they are shapes, somewhere they are cars, read about it more. About your sample, I guess problem is in `rand.Next(1,3)` in DispleyTimeEvent, random in programming is pseudo, and I think you get as a result value 1.

Comment: What is your problem exactly? And please, provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System;

namespace StackOverflow_OOP
{
    class Program
    {
        // Randomness removed: you want a driver to **consistently** pass or fail.
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Car car = new Car(VehicleFuelType.Petrol, 20);
            // The first arg specifies format/placement of the second
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Vehicle Type: {0}", car.Type);
            // In background, uses String.Format()
            // See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx

            Van van = new Van(VehicleFuelType.Diesel, 40);
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Vehicle Type: {0}", van.Type);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    // A string that only takes a small number of values is called an enumeration
    // See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx
    public enum VehicleFuelType
    {
        Petrol,
        Diesel,
        LPG
    }

    // Vehicle is clearly abstract in this context, while Car & Van are concrete.
    // See explaination after code.
    public abstract class Vehicle
    {
        public VehicleFuelType FuelType { get; }
        public int TankCap { get; }
        public double FuelInTank { get; private set; }
        public string Type { get { return this.GetType().Name; } }

        public Vehicle(VehicleFuelType fuelType, int tankCap, double fuelInTank)
        {
            FuelType = fuelType;
            TankCap = tankCap;
            FuelInTank = fuelInTank;
        }
    }

    public class Car : Vehicle
    {
        public Car(VehicleFuelType fuelType, double fuelInTank) : base(fuelType, 40, fuelInTank)
        {
        }
    }

    public class Van : Vehicle
    {
        public Van(VehicleFuelType fuelType, double fuelInTank) : base(fuelType, 80, fuelInTank)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

## Classes: Abstract vs. Concrete

```
public abstract class Shape
{
    public abstract double GetArea();
}

public class Circle : Shape
{
    public int Radius { get; }

    public Circle(int radius)
    {
        Radius = radius;
    }

    public override double GetArea()
    {
        return Math.PI * Radius * Radius;
    }
}

public class Square : Shape 
{
    public int SideLength { get; }

    public Square(int sideLength)
    {
        SideLength = sideLength;
    }

    public override double GetArea()
    {
        return SideLength * SideLength;
    }
}
```

The simplest difference between an abstract class and a concrete one: 
An **abstract class cannot be instantiated** (directly); a **concrete** one **can**.

For instance,

```
Shape shape = new Shape(); // impossible
Circle circle = new Circle(); // fine
```

Crucially,

```
Shape circle = new Circle(); // fine
```

Conceptually, it's impossible to create an abstract class (e.g. shape) without actually creating a concrete class (circle).

Even more simply, imagine going to a restaurant and telling the waiter you want "food". Obviously he can comply, but somewhere along the line "food" must become steak or tuna or spaghetti, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the direct problem you mentioned:

1. The problem is related to the WriteLine call.
2. The signature of the call you mane

   Console.Out.WriteLine("test", vehicle.carType);

   is

   public virtual void WriteLine(string format, object arg0)
3. So the first parameter in this call should have an item which you want to composite (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx for more details).
   bottom line the call should be something like

   Console.Out.WriteLine("test {0}", vehicle.carType);

Regarding the "polymorphism" you mentioned:

What you implemented isn't polymorphism.
You might want to read about polymorphism a little bit:

1. oop: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt656686.aspx
2. polymorphism: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx